# SQL Server - Select max

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a SQL Server stored procedure with an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE Sale_Sheet 
SET concluded = 'True'
    , concluded_time = GETDATE()
    , saleNumber = (SELECT MAX(saleNumber) + 1 FROM Sale_Sheet)
WHERE vatNumber = @vatNumber
  AND [user_id] = @user_id
```

It happens that two users initiate a procedure at the same time, and both users receive the same maximum value (`SELECT MAX(saleNumber) + 1 FROM Sale_Sheet`). How can I fix this?

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER() to only update one row.

Comment: Looks like you need an auto_increment column or a sequence.

Comment: Transactions perhaps?

Comment: You should use an `identity` column for `Sale_Sheet.saleNumber`.

Comment: whenever you see `id = (select max(id) + 1...)`, you're doing it wrong.